# "AecuInstallHook not found" error when building maven project

Tags: java, maven, aem

I had to re-install AEM6.5 on my local system after I could not open CRX and had other errors
building the project. AT that time, re-indexing, deleting/regenerating repoinit/repo.lock/cahe.lock, implementing all those suggestions found online : did not fix the issue.
So, I had to re-install AEM6.5 on my local system
with aem-service-pkg-6.5.12.0-NPR-38144-B0002 service pack.
Now when trying to build our maven project getting an error:

"Starting installation of subpackage ABC:abc.ui.content:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
Error during processing.
org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.packaging.PackageException: hook's main class de.valtech.aecu.core.installhook.AecuInstallHook not found: aecu"

Building code that definitely is good. Another developer built it without issue.
I do see AecuInstallHook as generated class in the project. So, it seems to exist.

At this point I am thinking to re-install again, but not sure any more if it will fix this issue.
What may be causing this error?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks